# Spring boot skips custom validation when using middleware service method between controller and service methods

Tags: spring-boot, validation

When I am calling from the controller to service method directly my @CustomValidation works and fires exception.

here is controller method

```
@PostMapping("doSomething")
public CustomInfo doSomething(@RequestBody(required = true) MyParam param) {
    CustomInfo info;
    try {
        info = myService.doSomething(param);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        info = new CustomInfo();
        info.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    }

    return info;
}
```

here is a service method

```
public CustomInfo doSomething(@CustomValidation MyParam param) {
    //do something
}
```

But if I use one more method in service in the middle of controller and validated method, it skips validation.

Here is middleware method example. assuming that we are calling doSomething1 method from controller.

```
public CustomInfo doSomething1(MyParam param) {
    return this.doSomething(param);
}
```

Why it skips validation? Or how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

This is service class

```
@Service
@Validated
public class MyService {
    //doSomething1 method
    //doSomething method
}
```

this is controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("rest/myRest")
public class MyRestController {
    //doSomething caller method
}
```

This is my custom validation annotation which checks required field in xsd schema based class.

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ParseRequiredFieldValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ParseRequiredField {
    String message() default "Please fill all required fields";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String[] ignoreFields() default {};
}
```

and here is validator

```
public class ParseRequiredFieldValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ParseRequiredField, Object> {

    private ParseRequiredField constraint;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ParseRequiredField constraint) {
        this.constraint = constraint;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Class<?> targetClass = value.getClass();
        List<String> ignoreFields = Arrays.asList(constraint.ignoreFields());

        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
        Field[] fields = targetClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if(!ignoreFields.contains(field.getName())) {
                XmlElement annotation = field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
                if (annotation != null && (annotation.required() && !annotation.nillable())) {
                    try {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        if (field.get(value) == null) {
                            if (errors.length() != 0) {
                                errors.append(" ");
                            }
                            String message = String.format("%s: required field '%s' is null.",
                                    targetClass.getSimpleName(),
                                    field.getName());

                            errors.append(message);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (errors.length() != 0) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(errors.toString())
                    .addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Validation like this is implemented using AOP. Spring uses proxy based aop and as such self invocation won't work. They don't pass through the proxy and as such the validation won't work, the same would apply to transactions for instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum is right. I thought that your middleware service was in a different class. It wont work like that, You need to either move the middleware service to a different bean or annotate it with your custom validator

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Now I know the reason